# How to iterate through empty array or object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an object or array like below:
"[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{\"subject\":\"Math\"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{\"subject\":\"Chemistry\"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]"

as well:
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{"subject":"Math"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{"subject":"Chemistry"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

when i am iterating it using foreach loop it show " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\eschool\cms\admin\scripts\time-table-add-submit.php on line 11 "
May be due to the empty value at the beginning and at the end. but I want to iterate it somehow how to do that. Heres my code:
JavaScript:

```
var timeTableSub = [
       {"subject": timeTableSub1},
       {"subject": timeTableSub2},
       ... Like Wise....
       {"subject": timeTableSub42}
];
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(timeTableSub);

$.ajax({
        url: "scripts/time-table-add-submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data:{
            'arrayList': jsonArray
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#tempDiv").html(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$arrayList = json_encode($_POST['arrayList'], TRUE);

echo $arrayList."<br>";
$newArray = json_decode($arrayList);
echo $newArray."<br>";




foreach ($newArray as $key => $value)
{
      echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

?>

Comment: ANd what's the point of encoding and decoding data?

Comment: just to check the data i have, nothing else.

Comment: you don't need `$arrayList = json_encode($_POST['arrayList'], TRUE);` because what you've sent from the browser is **already** JSON. And therefore you should be writing `$newArray = json_decode($_POST['arrayList']);` instead later on as well

Comment: Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/320ea1ea8665fe3a2915c896c9210b2d2bfb8479

Comment: thanx @ADyson now I'm getting the result but empty value lost. Is there a way it should print like "subject: " if it is empty

Comment: Got it @ADyson thanx for your support.

Comment: Thanx all for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be stringifying the data twice, once on the front end during the request with JSON.stringify and once more when receiving the POST object by encoding it once more.

Removing either would fix this issue.

Comment: following php is not working too.     <?php
    $arrayList = $_POST['arrayList'];
    


    foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value)
    {
          echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
    }


?>

Comment: could you please send me the code to do it right. Thanx

Comment: Okay so imagine encoding or stringifying your object as packing the data in a box.  

What you were doing by stringifying/encoding twice is packing the data into 2 boxes, but only unpacking once (with your `json_decode`).  

When I said to remove either the `JSON.stringify` or `json_encode`, you removed the `json_encode` (packing) AND the `json_decode` (unpacking).  

What that meant was you went from unpacking it once from 2 boxes (1 box still left), to unpacking it NO times from 1 box (1 box still left), i.e. same issue.  

Adding your `json_decode` back in would fix it.

Comment: I understood what you advised me. for example  I'm doing this: hello=encode1=encode2=decode2 and the data is still in the form of ecoded1.

Comment: Now i'll doing it right and getting what I want as specified.

Comment: thanx @jmcgrory

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to mark my answer as useful if it was so 